# Ansible "hip-profiles unexpected here" Palo alto panos_security_rule

Tags: python, ansible, yaml, palo-alto-networks

I'm trying to set a security policy on my Palo Alto firewalls using Ansible with the `panos_security_rule` module.

However, I keep running in to the same error, `hip-profiles unexpected here`.

I found [multiple reports](https://www.reddit.com/r/paloaltonetworks/comments/rhqm95/post_1013h1_issues_anyone_ever_seen_this/) on the problem, even a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/PaloAltoNetworks/pan-os-python/issues/441) on the official Palo Alto repository.

My firewalls are on version 10.0.8 and 10.0.9, does anyone know how to work around this issue?
I don't know how long it will take before the GitHub issue is resolved, and can not really wait for a fix update. I thought maybe there is a workaround to prevent a hip-profiles variable to be part of the final config xml file that is being pushed to the firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI--in case no one responded.  My pull request to that issue was merged and released in the 1.7.2 release of pan-os-python.  Upgrading that should help going forward.